# Using Spotify API with Django and react

Tags: reactjs, django, rest, spotify, audio-player

I was experimenting with the Spotify API with Django, and recently found out that you cant control the playback unless you have a premium account. Is there a way to stream the music from spotify into a component using react, the same way how discord bots can play music from spotify in a voice channel? If this doesnt work, is there any other way to achieve this same goal?

Comment: That is a new feature that is in beta phase and even if you use it only premium users will be able to use the app you build. I would suggest sound cloud - but you won't get copyrighted music ig.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @rohan-asokan Spotify playback api is still in beta phase, even if you use it only premium users will be able to use the app you build and right now sound cloud dev apps are on hold.

> SoundCloud Application Registration Due to the high amount of requests
> recently received, we will no longer be processing API application
> requests at this time. We are working to re-evaluate our process to
> make it more efficient.

So i think you should follow [this](https://thegamedefault.medium.com/create-your-own-media-streaming-platform-using-open-source-technologies-90f08138465b) article if you are interested in creating your own platform.